# Powershell click on javascript link

Tags: javascript, powershell, powershell-3.0

Here is hyperlink code

```
<a href="javascript:void(1)" onclick="server_playOn(17,2, 'est', this);">
                     Example  
                  </a>
```

Here is my current powershell code.

```
Get-Process iexplore | Foreach-Object { $_.CloseMainWindow() }
$username = "user" 
$password = "pass"
$ie = New-Object -comobject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.FullScreen=$true
$ie.navigate("http://www.example.com/en/index.shtml")
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100}
trap [Exception] 
{ 
    # This will happen if you're already logged in 
    if($_.Exception.Message -eq "Property 'value' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable." -Or $_.Exception.Message -eq "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.") 
    { 
        # Try and skip this error 
        continue; } 
    else { 
        # Fail for other Exceptions 
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $_.Exception.Message; } 
    }

##if not logged in
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Logging into example.com";
$ie.document.getElementById("username").value = "$username"
$ie.document.getElementById("pass").value = "$password"
$ie.document.getElementById("frmLogin").submit()
start-sleep 5
$ie.navigate("http://www.example.com/en/link5.shtml")
##need to add click code here
```

Comment: Just a thought, but if you don't mind using a 3rd party library to accomplish this, then you could use something like the Selenium PowerShell eXtensions (http://sepsx.codeplex.com/).  Selenium has a much better API for interacting with HTML Elements.

Comment: Thanks robert. I'll keep in mind, if since I don't know how to use it but will give it try.

Comment: @JPBlanc See the answer which is marked as accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add these lines at the end of the script:

```
$link = @($ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A')) | Where-Object {$_.innerText -eq 'Example'}
$link.click()
```

Comment: Awesome man. I was hoping you would answer my question and you did. I read many for your answers they are very helpful.

Comment: Can you help me bit. I am facing bit of a problem. How can I make it work if the link I need to click. it is in a iframe. is there a workaround for that ? thanks

Comment: IIRC you'll need to navigate to the iframe page, get the link and click it.

Comment: Shay, please check this img of source code. looks like it is not `iframe` for this html page. powershell is not clicking the link please help. http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7333/9034029697_2a2b56c447_o.png

Comment: You need to click the link that says: 'Life OK' ?

Comment: Yes, I need click on link that says 'Life OK'

Comment: Look at the code example I posted, replace 'Example' with 'Life OK'.

Comment: I have test your code on different page to see if it works and it does work on the other page, hyperlink is just normal link. but for this site is not clicking it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be

```
$ie.Document.parentWindow.execScript($Javascript, "javascript")
```