# Powershell script; click javascript link

Tags: javascript, powershell, serial-port

I'm writing a login script that will sit in the background and pass serial port data to a web page.
I've gotten everything working but the last click.  Based on these two posts:

[Powershell click on javascript link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17077386/powershell-click-on-javascript-link)
[Execute javascript trough Internet Explorer's com interface using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444330/execute-javascript-trough-internet-explorers-com-interface-using-powershell)

This is my script:

```
# Variables
$username = "user"
$password = "pass"
$item = ""
$portnumber = "COM6"
#open port and wait for data
$port = new-object system.io.ports.serialport $portnumber,9600,none,8,one
$port | add-member -membertype "NoteProperty" -name "identifier" -value "Serial"
$port.open()
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible=$true

Function Login($name,$pass){
$ie.navigate2("http://site/login.aspx")
while($ie.busy) {start-sleep -s 1}
$ie.document.getElementById("LoginName").value= $name
sleep -s 1
$ie.document.getElementById("Password").value = $pass
sleep -s 1
$ie.document.getElementById("LoginBtn").click()
sleep -s 2
}

Function Lookup($itemnumber){
$ie.navigate2("http://site/itemLookup.aspx")
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -s 1}
$ie.document.getElementById("ctl00_PageBody_ItemNumberBox").value = $itemnumber
sleep -s 1
$ie.document.getElementById("ctl00_PageBody_RetrieveButton").click()
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -s 1}
sleep -s 2
$details = @( $ie.document.getelementsbytagname('a')) | where-object {$_.innerText -eq 'Details'}
$details.click()
}

try{
Do{
    $itemno = $port.readline()
    write-host $itemno
    #check for ie not timed-out
    if (!($ie.navigate2("http://site/dashboard.aspx"))) {
        sleep -s 2
        Login -name $username -pass $password
        Lookup -itemnumber $itemno
    }
    else { Lookup -itemnumber $itemno }
    }
while ($port.isopen -eq $true)
}#end try
catch{"$_" ; $ie.quit(); $port.close(); $port.dispose(); exit}
```

In the Lookup function is where I'm having trouble.  I can run each line in a console and it works fine, but as a script it fails at assigning the $details variable, and therefore won't load the last page.

This is the page element I'm trying to interact with:

```
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <p id="ctl00_PageBody_ItemInfoPara" class="tabletext">This item's status is Normal. [<a href="javascript://" onclick='ViewItemInformation(11770856,false);'">Details</a>]</p>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
```

Is this something to do with scope?  Or am I just interacting with the page incorrectly?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I was able to get this working by folding the two functions into one Main function, so it seems to be a scope issue.  Any ideas on how to resolve that?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$ie.document.getElementById("ctl00_PageBody_RetrieveButton").click()`
try to click on the firstchild:  `$ie.document.getElementById("ctl00_PageBody_RetrieveButton").firstchild.click()`

since it's not the `<p>` block, but the `<a>` block within it